# Iterate through dictionary with respect to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, loops

I have a nested dictionary as follows:

```
student_loan_portfolio = {
    'loan1': {'rate': .078, 'balance': 1000, 'payment': 100, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan2': {'rate': .0645, 'balance': 10, 'payment': 5, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan3': {'rate': .0871, 'balance': 250, 'payment': 60, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan4': {'rate': .0842, 'balance': 200, 'payment': 37, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan5': {'rate': .054, 'balance': 409, 'payment': 49, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan6': {'rate': .055, 'balance': 350, 'payment': 50, 'prepayment': 0}
}
```

I would like to iterate through the containing dictionary (with keys `loan1` through `loan6`) in order of the key containing the dictionary with the highest 'rate' value in its respective nested dictionary. That is, I would like to iterate in order of  `loan3`, `loan4`, `loan1`, `loan2`, `loan6`, `loan5`

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
sorted(student_loan_portfolio.items(), key=lambda (k,v): v['rate'], reverse=True)
```

(Thanks @MarkReed, you're right. To sort in descending order we need either `-v['rate']` or, as I've shown above, passing `reverse=True` to `sorted`.)

Comment: Except OP wants it the other way around, highest first.  So the key should be `-v['rate']`.  (Or `reverse=True`, which is an option I'd forgotten about, as I'm only an infrequent Python programmer. Thanks for the reminder!)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values like this:

`sorted(student_loan_portfolio.items(), key=lambda (name,portfolio): portfolio['rate'], reverse=True)
[('loan3', {'rate': 0.0871, 'balance': 250, 'payment': 60, 'prepayment': 0}), ('loan4', {'rate': 0.0842, 'balance': 200, 'payment': 37, 'prepayment': 0}), ('loan1', {'rate': 0.078, 'balance': 1000, 'payment': 100, 'prepayment': 0}), ('loan2', {'rate': 0.0645, 'balance': 10, 'payment': 5, 'prepayment': 0}), ('loan6', {'rate': 0.055, 'balance': 350, 'payment': 50, 'prepayment': 0}), ('loan5', {'rate': 0.054, 'balance': 409, 'payment': 49, 'prepayment': 0})]`

See this page for more details on how to complex sorting in python works:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/